# Bootstrap Hover Dropdown Plugin not works in durandal view nav.html

Tags: requirejs, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

I am using hot towel SPA template.
i am trying to use at [Bootstrap Hover Dropdown Plugin](https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown) but hover over drop down effect never triggers.

nav.html contains

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false">
    Account <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Change Email</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Steps to reproduce.
1) create Application using Hot Towel SPA template
2) add bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js in vendors bundel
3) replace the nav.html code with the code above.

same nav.html code pasted above applicationHost div does trigers hover drop down effect. But when injected using durandal. it doesn't work.

Comment: Zip me your VS solution and I'll take a look.

Comment: thankyou so much zip fie is at http://we.tl/Z6kk2K4VCv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to have the dropdown hover working:

- in your nav.html file: remove the last line `<script src="../../TemplateFiles/assets/hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>`not needed here.
- in your shell.js file: add the following function:

  ```
  function compositionComplete() {
      $('[data-hover="dropdown"]').dropdownHover();
  }
  ```

And also modify your shell var as below:

```
    var shell = {
        activate: activate,
        compositionComplete: compositionComplete,
        router: router
    };
```

That's all!

The trick here: in the `compositionComplete` function I 'force' the initialisation of the dropdown hover effect. If you take a look in the plugin source file, at the end of the file you have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // apply dropdownHover to all elements with the data-hover="dropdown" attribute
    $('[data-hover="dropdown"]').dropdownHover();
});
```

In a more 'classic' situation you have nothing to do (except reference the source plugin). The problem with Durandal is that this is not triggered so I do it in the `compositionComplete`.

Hope I'm clear.

Comment: i just can show my gratitude. thank you so so so much. i was waiting for this for weeks. spent so many nights on this. really grateful . 

One question is that i am actually using a html5 css template. Templates comes with many UI related javascript files. e.g. slider. same way my slider wasnt working when tried to insert using durandal view. So i should be doing the same for these as well ? i.e. triggering the ready function ??

Comment: there was a function to trigger the slider jQuery("#layerslider").layerSlider({ i put this code in compositionComplete it worked :) Thankyou so much. :)

Comment: Yes try to proceed the same. If you still have problems, don't hesitate to ask me and I'll try to help you. Good luck!